# Binary Search in C

Tags: c, binary-search

I implemented a search function of elements of the list that it was a binary search returns the index of the element found.  My curiosity is to have a method of the binary search you could print all occurrences of the element in the list.

Below is the code

```
int Binary_Search(int *array, int chave , int N) {
    int inf = 0; 
    int sup = N-1; 
    int meio;
    while (inf <= sup) {
        meio = inf + (sup-inf)/2;
        if (chave == array[meio])
            return meio;
        else if (chave < array[meio])
            sup = meio-1;
        else
            inf = meio+1;
    }

    return -1;   
}
```

part of the other source

How could I make this code snippet only print occurrences duplicated?

```
else {
    Imprime_Struct(Tabinvertida_Fornecedor[aux]->info);
    aux=aux+1;
    while (aux != i) {
        if (strcmp(chave, TabName[aux]->info.name)==0)
            Print_Struct(TabName[aux]->info);
        aux++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Your initial binary search is fine for search an array of integers. Your second snippet seems to be dealing with an array of a data structure.  Is 'Imprime_Struct()' different from `Print_Struct()`? You could write two variants of the binary search, one which finds the smallest index where the value is equal to the value being sought, and one which finds the largest index where the value is equal to the value being sought (in an array with duplicates). These are both O(log N) algorithms, better than an O(N) algorithm.

Comment: Binary-Search Algorithm is meant to find the index of an element which you want to search in a sorted array. In case, if you have multiple occurrences of the same element (which you are searching) in the array, then it should give you only the first occurring index position. Binary-Search Algorithm can never return more than one index positions where the element is found.

Answer (score 2):

Your function assumes that the array is sorted in descending order. You can modify it to find the location of the first match, if any, and list all matches:

```
void list_all_matches(const int *array, int N, int chave) {
    int meio, inf = 0, sup = N; 
    while (inf < sup) {
        meio = inf + (sup - inf) / 2;
        if (chave < array[meio])
            sup = meio;
        else
            inf = meio;
    }
    while (sup < N && array[sup] == chave)
        printf("%d\n", sup++);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement binary search two ways:

```
1) so that it finds the first element not smaller than given
2) so that it finds the last element not greater than given
```

Using these two implementations combined you can easily determine the number of copies of each element.

If your array contains integeres only, you don't event have to use both - just pick one and search for

```
1) n and n+1
2) n-1 and n
```

respectively.

That gives you logarithmic complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the `index` of the element, you can just `scan forward and backwards` checking for that element. As the array is `sorted`, all the `duplicates will be together`. In the `worst case` when all the elements are same, this method would take `O(n)`